# about sstream, using a variable as array size and calculation overflow

Tags: c++, arrays, overflow, sstream

It is required to read from a text file without knowing the size of array once and then calculate the mean and variance.
Now I cant create the specific arrays.  As a result, I cant calculate the mean and variance.
I really hope that you guys can help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include "fraction.h"

using namespace std;

void ascending(fraction fractionarr[]);
fraction mean(fraction fractionarr[]);
fraction variance(fraction fractionarr[]);
static const int countlinenumber(ifstream& data);


void ascending(fraction fractionarr[])
{
ifstream data("data1.txt");
fraction temp;
fraction test(0, 1);
int n = 0;
int linenumber = countlinenumber(data);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if(fractionarr[i] != test)
    {
        n++;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < linenumber; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < linenumber-1; j++)
    {
        if(fractionarr[i+1] != test)
        {
            if(fractionarr[j] > fractionarr[j+1])
            {
                temp = fractionarr[j];
                fractionarr[j] = fractionarr[j+1];
                fractionarr[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
}

fraction mean(fraction fractionarr[])
{
ifstream data("data1.txt");
fraction sum = fractionarr[0];
fraction average;
fraction n(1,1);
fraction test(0,1);
int linenumber = countlinenumber(data);

for (int i = 1; i < linenumber; i++)
{
    if(fractionarr[i] != test)
    {
        sum = sum + fractionarr[i];
        n = n + fraction(1,1);
    }
}

average = sum / n;
return average;
}  

fraction variance(fraction fractionarr[])
{
ifstream data("data1.txt");
fraction average = mean(fractionarr);
fraction* semi = new fraction[100];
fraction total;
fraction t(1, 1);
fraction variance;
fraction test(0,1);
int linenumber = countlinenumber(data);

for (int i = 0; i < linenumber; i++)
{
    if(fractionarr[i] != test)
    {
        semi[i] = (fractionarr[i]-average) * (fractionarr[i]-average);
        t = t + fraction(1, 1); 
    }
}
total = semi[0];
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
    if(semi[i] != test)
    {
        total = total + semi[i];
    }
}
variance = total / t;
return variance;
}

static const int countlinenumber(ifstream& data)
{
string temp;
int linenumber = 0;

while(getline(data, temp) && !data.eof())
{
    linenumber++;
}
return linenumber;
}

int main()
{
ifstream data("data1.txt");
ofstream data_out("data1_out.txt");
stringstream ss;

string temp;
char op;
fraction testing(0,1);
fraction average;
static const int linenumber = countlinenumber(data);

int* numerator = new int[linenumber];
int* denominator = new int[linenumber];
fraction* fractionarr = new fraction[linenumber];

for(int i = 0; i < linenumber; i++)
{
    numerator[i] = 0;
    denominator[i] = 0;
}

for(int i = 0; i < linenumber; i++)
{
    if(!data.eof())
    {
        getline(data, temp, '\n');
        ss << temp;
        ss >> numerator[i] >> op >> denominator[i];
        ss.clear();
    }
}
delete [] numerator;
delete [] denominator;

ascending(fractionarr);
for (int i = 0; i < linenumber; i++)
{
    if(fractionarr[i] != testing)
        data_out << fractionarr[i] << endl;
}
data_out.close();

cout << mean(fractionarr) << endl;
average = mean(fractionarr);
cout << variance(fractionarr) << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;


}
```

Comment: What does 'I cant create the specific arrays' mean? Looks to me like you do create the arrays. The main problem with your code seems to be the file handling, which is all over the place.

Comment: `std::vector` to the rescue.

Comment: Also you're reading the file several times, but you've been asked to read a text file once. I guess what this question is really about is, how can I read the data into an array when I don't know the size of the array beforehand and I'm not allowed to reread the data? One answer is to use std::vector as Jerry says, but I guess you have to use arrays. If that's the case then you have to *resize* the array when you know you need a bigger array. So the array starts small but you increase it's size as you read more and more data.

Comment: @john i think i do...but when i compile the whole thing, the numerator  array and denominator array are absent...

Comment: @JerryCoffin I havent learnt std::vector before...and i have googled this topic for a few days but still cant figure it out

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this looks enough like homework that I feel compelled to provide only an idea of a direction instead of a complete solution to do everything you've asked for. I hope this is enough to get you started though:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int main(){
    std::istringstream input("1 200 50 9.5 300.1");

    std::vector<double> numbers{std::istream_iterator<double>(input), 
                    std::istream_iterator<double>()};

    double sum = std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0.0);

    std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << "\n";
    std::cout << "Count: " << numbers.size() << "\n";
}
```

This doesn't compute the mean or variance, but based on what's here, I believe adding computation of the mean should be truly trivial, and the variance only a little more difficult (note: for the variance you'll want the version of `std::accumulate` that uses a lambda to compute each squared difference from the mean).

Comment: do i have to use those functions in vector?

Comment: @user2847449: There are lots of different ways to do the job, but this (IMO) one of the simpler ones.

Comment: may i ask what the meaning of 
"std::vector<double> numbers{std::istream_iterator<double>(input), 
                    std::istream_iterator<double>()};"

Comment: @user2847449: it's initializing the vector from the iterators, which read the data from the stream.

Comment: but when i type that line into my visual studio, there is an error saying "expected a ';'"...

Comment: @user2847449: You're probably using an older copy of VS. Try: `std::vector<double> numbers((std::istream_iterator<double>(input)), 
                    std::istream_iterator<double>());` instead.